# google extension is not accepting script-src exceptions in V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

from what I've researched here in the community, adding the code below to `manifest.json` should at least allow exceptions for scripts in the whitelist, but it seems like it's no longer allowed to use injected, except if the scripts are  added by `src` tag. Could someone help me confirm because I can't find anything in the documentation (or I didn't look it right in the API)

manifest.json:

```
...
,"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://example.com;",
    "sandbox": "sandbox default-src 'self';"
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just posted and found the answer right after... as I didn't find anything on the forum, I'll leave it there in case anyone has doubts:

> ...
> MV3 disallows certain CSP modifications for extension_pages that were
> permitted in MV2. The script-src, object-src, and worker-src
> directives may only have the following values:
>
> self none Any localhost source, (http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1,
> or any port on those domains) CSP modifications for sandbox have no
> such new restrictions.
> ...
>
> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy

Therefore, just by an injection like:

```
const node = document.createElement('script');
node.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('./script.js');
node.onload = function(){ this.remove() };
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(node);
```

Comment: A question about CSP for sandboxes pages. Take a look at this [official doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy). It says that `"CSP modifications for sandbox have no such new restrictions"`. However, when you try to specify a URL for `script-src` in CSP for sandboxed page, using the [example given on this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/), the browser still refuses it by saying, `'content_security_policy.sandbox': Ignored insecure CSP value "https://example.com" in directive 'script-src'`